# mail() function aparently working emails not arriving

Tags: php

Hi first i test the mail function, allowing errors to be displayed and using this to test.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


$email = "demo@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test Message";
$msg = "This is a test message";

$eLog="/tmp/mailError.log";

//Get the size of the error log
//ensure it exists, create it if it doesn't
$fh= fopen($eLog, "a+");
fclose($fh);
$originalsize = filesize($eLog);

mail($email,$subject,$msg);

/*
* NOTE: PHP caches file status so we need to clear
* that cache so we can get the current file size
*/

clearstatcache();
$finalsize = filesize($eLog);

//Check if the error log was just updated
if ($originalsize != $finalsize) {
print "Problem sending mail. (size was $originalsize, now $finalsize) See $eLog
";
} else {
print "Mail sent to $email";
}
?>
```

This is telling me that this is working and sending the email..

The problem is the mail that should be sent with this code, is not arriving to demo@gmail.com account (wich i change for a real email)

Why? also in php.ini seems to be fine, but maybe im not looking for the right parameter.

Comment: 1) check the return value of mail() 2) check the server's mail log to see what happens when php hands over the email. 3) check your receiving account's spam folder.

Comment: Also do some troubleshooting.  Comment out the mail() line and add a basic one to see if that works.  mail('demo@gmail.com','test','some content');  Then you will at least know if it is something in your code or not.

Comment: ok 1) how? . 2) i check /tmp/mailError.log not errors there, 3) i did not emails there :(

Comment: @ Steve done that.. not erros throw, but email is not arraiving

Comment: Check the return status of your `mail()` function. If it has returned `true` then your email has been accepted for transmission. After that you're debugging email, not code, so you're a bit off topic for [so]. There are 100 reasons why mail might not be delivered, which makes this too broad for a simple Q & A.

Comment: Why the downvote?? damn i hate that , anyway i think the problem is sendmail in linux as i have linode http://whiletruecode.com/post/setting-up-phps-mail-function-on-a-linode-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont care about that downvote, ok i finally understasnd whats going on this should help another "not god programmer" a mortal one, like me..

If you are on a linux server, it seems mail () function are sent to sendmail function , to enable this you must install postfix.

this is very easy.. and solve all my issues.

http://whiletruecode.com/post/setting-up-phps-mail-function-on-a-linode-server

Comment: Personally, I think this could prove to be useful for many. I lost count as to how many times I've seen questions in regards to the same or similar problem.

Comment: Yes, and this issue will have to be some of the first things to check is always left to the last... thats why i also think this is usefull.. In Linode for example you always have to install postfix or mail() wont work.

Comment: It's good information to know. I for one did not know till now, thanks. Cheers